# Django ) Postgresql model ERROR

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

In models.py in my app of django, I have a model below :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import *

class lkmModel(models.Model):

    #Profile Image
    profileUrls = ArrayField(base_field=models.TextField,size=5)
    #profileUrls = models.TextField()
    """profileUrl2 = models.TextField()
    profileUrl3 = models.TextField()
    profileUrl4 = models.TextField()
    profileUrl5 = models.TextField()"""
    #Profile Basic
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    residence = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    bloodType = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    religion = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    #KEY_WORD
    personaltiy = models.TextField()
    appearance = models.TextField()
    hobby = models.TextField()
    ability = models.TextField()
    idealType = models.TextField()
    career = models.TextField()
    best = models.TextField()
    badges = ArrayField(base_field=models.CharField(max_length=10))
    manual = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name
```

I'm trying to create an instance of lkmModel in models.py at lkm.py
Correspondent codes of lkm.py are below :

```
from myApp.models import lkmModel

def createModel(self,pictures,basics,keywords,badges,manual):
    lkmModelOne = lkmModel(profileUrls = pictures, name = basics[0] , status = basics[1] ,
                      bloodType = basics[2] , age = basics[3] , religion = basics[4] , residence = basics[5],
                      personality= keywords[0], appearance = keywords[1] , hobby = keywords[2] , ability = keywords[3],
                      idealType = keywords[4], career = keywords[5] , best = keywords[6], badges = badges , manual = manual)
    lkmModelOne.save()
```

When lkm.py is executed , I got an error below:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kyungmoon/projectDicrectory/project/myApp/lkm.py", line 8, in <module>
    from myApp.models import lkmModel
  File "/Users/kyungmoon/projectDicrectory/project/myApp/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.postgres.fields import *
  File "/Users/kyungmoon/venv/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/fields/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .array import *  # NOQA
  File "/Users/kyungmoon/venv/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/fields/array.py", line 207, in <module>
    class ArrayLenTransform(Transform):
  File "/Users/kyungmoon/venv/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/fields/array.py", line 209, in ArrayLenTransform
    output_field = IntegerField()
  File "/Users/kyungmoon/venv/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/Users/kyungmoon/venv/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/kyungmoon/venv/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

As you see, the error is from postgresql and arrayField of postgresql.
But in models.py , I created a lkmModel in a right way, isn't it?

Why does this happen?

I did install postgresql in my local machine and created a db called lkmDB and a table for this.
My DATABASES setting in settings.py in project is below :

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'lkmDB',
    'USER': 'kyungmoon',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

None of this has anything whatsoever to do with the code you've posted.

You are presumably doing this in a plain Python shell; you should start up the Django shell with `python manage.py shell` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your replay! I did execute lkm.py with Pycharm IDE, is it different from the way executing by 'python manage.py shell'? Pycharm is already running with virtualenv.

Comment: I don't know anything about Pycharm, but I guess it has some way of configuring it to run Django properly. And I'm sorry, I can't understand your second comment at all.